# Which type signature can be used to memoize a generic method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, memoization

I have a memoization function 'Memo' and I want to pass generic method 'Foo' to it as a delegate, which type signature can I use to achieve this?

```
public static class Program
{

    private static Func<int, int> Foo(int n)
    {
        return (int x) =>
        {
            if (n <= 2) return x;
            return Foo(n - 1)(1) + Foo(n - 2)(1);
        };
    } 

    private static Func<A, B> Memo<A, B>(Func<A, B> f)
    {
    var cache = new Dictionary<A, B>();
        return (A a) =>
    {
        if (cache.ContainsKey(a))
        {
            return cache[a];
        }
        var b = f(a);
        cache[a] = b;
        return b;
    }; 
}
```

Comment: Isn't your `Foo` supposed to be a `Fib`? Shouldn't `Foo` return an `int`? Or is returning a `Func<int, int>` intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods are implicitly convertible to an `Action` / `Func` that matches their signature, so you can do this:

```
Func<int, Func<int, int>> foo = Foo;
Memo(foo);
```

Now that `foo` has a type, the generic arguments of `Memo` can be inferred.